# Problem with providers not assigned, rl-agents, when exporting .onnx file

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, godot, onnxruntime

I was trying to create an AI using rl-agents with godot. It all went fine until the exporting process.

It occurred the following error:

raise ValueError(
ValueError: This ORT build has ['AzureExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'] enabled. Since ORT 1.9, you are required to explicitly set the providers parameter when instantiating InferenceSession. For example, onnxruntime.InferenceSession(..., providers=['AzureExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'], ...)

I tried to include the providers as it told me, in the onnxruntime.InferenceSession() function, but nothing changed.

The files that are supposed to be the error are: stable_baselines3.py, stable_baselines_export.py, onnxruntime_inference_collection.py.

I'm new to all of this, just trying to solve it.

Tried to export the .onnx file, but it exports with errors. Then the file is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with defining this agrument explicit:

> providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']

Comment: It did solve the problem, but now there is a "Mismatch in action output".

assert np.allclose(action_sb3, action_onnx, atol=1e-5), "Mismatch in action output"

It seems like its comparing the action output, action_sb3 is defined as:

with torch.no_grad():
            action_sb3, _, _ = sb3_model(obs2, deterministic=True)

and action_onnx is: 

obs = [v for v in obs.values()]
        action_onnx, state_outs = ort_sess.run(None, {"obs": obs, "state_ins": np.array([0.0], dtype=np.float32)})

Answer (score 0):

i solve it like this :

python -m pip install -U pip

pip uninstall -y onnx onnxruntime onnxruntime-gpu onnxruntime-silicon

pip uninstall -y onnxruntime-extensions <<<<< This i didn't have it, but i tried.

pip install onnx==1.14.0 onnxruntime==1.15.0

Thanks!